# dynamically defining instance methods but not class methods

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Ruby 1.9.3: I am trying to implement a method which takes as argument a class, a symbol and a proc and defines (eventually overwriting) a new instance method for that class, but **not** a class method so that this test should pass:

```
require 'test/unit'

include Test::Unit::Assertions

class String
  def my_method
    'my_method'
  end
end

def define_instance_method(klass, method, &block)
  # klass.send :define_method, method, &block
  # ...
end

define_instance_method(Object, :my_method) { 'define_instance_method my_method' }
define_instance_method(String, :my_method) { 'define_instance_method my_method' }

assert Object.new.my_method == 'define_instance_method my_method'
assert_raise(NoMethodError) { Object.my_method }

assert String.new.my_method == 'define_instance_method my_method'
assert_raise(NoMethodError) { String.my_method }
```

I did many tryings (`define_method`, `define_singleton_method`, `class_eval`, `instance_eval`, `instance_exec`, `module_eval`...) but with no success; do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ProGNOMmers, recall that objects in Ruby are classes and classes are objects.

So everything in Ruby are objects, even classes :)

And when you define a method inside `Object` it will also be available to `Class` as well as to any class that inherits from `Object`.

That's mean to all classes.

Some proof:

```
define_instance_method(String, :my_method) { 'define_instance_method my_method' }

p String.new.my_method
p String.my_method

# =>  "define_instance_method my_method"
# =>  stackoverflow.rb:11:in `<main>': undefined method `my_method' for String:Class (NoMethodError)
```

See, your method not yet defined inside `Object`, thus not available inside `String`.

Now let's  do it:

```
define_instance_method(Object, :my_method) { 'define_instance_method my_method' }

p String.my_method
# => "define_instance_method my_method"

p Array.my_method
# => "define_instance_method my_method"

p NilClass.my_method
# => "define_instance_method my_method"
```

So just comment `define_instance_method(Object...` in your tests
and `String` specs will pass just well.

#### [Here are some crash tests](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=dynamically-defining-instance-methods-but-not-class-methods.rb&run=true)

Answer (score 1):

class_eval should work for you. Let me know why it isn't working for you

```
class A
end

A.class_eval do
  define_method(:foo) {puts 'hello'}
end

A.new.foo #hello
A.foo     #NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for A:Class
```

Comment: It doesn't work: `Object.my_method` does not raise a `NoMethodError`